# Selenium Chrome Driver v92: No connection (in v91 everything works fine)

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I updated to Chrome v92 (new chromedriver 92.0.4515.43 was downloaded and chrome browser updated to v92 automatically)

But now our tests doesn't work anymore when starting by jenkins. When i start the tests manually everything works in headless mode.

The following error occurs via jenkins:

```
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created
from disconnected: Unable to receive message from renderer
  (Session info: headless chrome=92.0.4515.107)
Build info: version: '4.0.0-beta-3', revision: '5d108f9a67'
System info: host: 'xxx' ip: 'xxxx', os.name: 'Windows Server 2016', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_202'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {desiredCapabilities=Capabilities {acceptSslCerts: true, browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--disable-notifications, --disable-popup-blocking, --headless, --disable-gpu], extensions: [], prefs: {download.default_directory: C:\xxxx\, profile.default_content_settings.popups: 0}}, pageLoadStrategy: normal}}]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:84)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:62)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:156)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:153)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:128)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:619)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:251)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:173)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:89)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:99)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:86)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:75)
```

This is the code, chrome is initialized

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", FilePath + "\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", FilePath);
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
HashMap<String, Object> chromeOptionsMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
options.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
options.addArguments("--disable-popup-blocking");
options.addArguments("--headless");
options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
options.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptionsMap);
options.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
options.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
options.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NORMAL);
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

When installing Chrome v91 with chromedriver v91 everything works fine. So the problem has to do with the update to v92.

Has anybody an idea?

Sometimes this error occurs:

```
org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.ConnectionFailedException: Unable to establish websocket connection to http://localhost:60650/devtools/browser/9faa33dd-c789-47f4-acab-261acc7045e7
Build info: version: '4.0.0-beta-3', revision: '5d108f9a67'
System info: host: 'xxx', ip: 'xxx', os.name: 'Windows Server 2016', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_202'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyWebSocket.<init>(NettyWebSocket.java:104)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyWebSocket.lambda$create$3(NettyWebSocket.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient.openSocket(NettyClient.java:111)
    at org.openqa.selenium.devtools.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:73)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.lambda$new$1(ChromiumDriver.java:102)
    at java.util.Optional.map(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:100)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:99)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:86)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.ConnectionFailedException: Unable to establish websocket connection to http://localhost:60650/devtools/browser/9faa33dd-c789-47f4-acab-261acc7045e7
Build info: version: '4.0.0-beta-3', revision: '5d108f9a67'
System info: host: 'xxx', ip: 'xxx', os.name: 'Windows Server 2016', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_202'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyWebSocket.<init>(NettyWebSocket.java:104)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyWebSocket.lambda$create$3(NettyWebSocket.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.netty.NettyClient.openSocket(NettyClient.java:111)
    at org.openqa.selenium.devtools.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:73)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.lambda$new$1(ChromiumDriver.java:102)
    at java.util.Optional.map(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:100)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:99)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:86)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: I am having the same issue with the chrome version 92. It works in headless mode, but with the actual browser, it gets stuck at the data; page and loading forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try to execute your code with:**

```
options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
```

The /dev/shm partition is too small in certain VM environments, causing Chrome to fail or crash (see http://crbug.com/715363). Use this flag to work-around this issue (a temporary directory will always be used to create anonymous shared memory files).

**Ref:**

https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

Answer (score 1):

adding these 2 lines of code worked for me:

> options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
>
> options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");

Answer (score 0):

Add the following chromeoptions:

```
ChromeOptions co = new ChromeOptions();
co.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(co);
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ChromeOptions co = new ChromeOptions();    
co.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
driver = new ChromeDriver(co);
```

try using this, it worked for me